# stateChangeStart event called twice per instance of controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a "notify unsaved changed" solution in angularjs.

Basically I have a `BaseForm` controller where I listen to the `stateChangeStart` event. When fired I check if the firm is dirty and if, when prompted, the user confirms to change location. If he doesn't than I `preventDefault()`.
Here is the code I used to achieve this :

```
this.$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
        let dirtyForms = this.detailForms.filter((form) => { if (form) { return form.$dirty } });
        if (dirtyForms.length && !confirm("Are you sure to leave this page?")) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }                
});
```

For some reason however, **if I navigate to a state managed by the same instance of controller the event is fired twice** and therefore I get prompted twice.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same instance, and the controller isn't being destroyed and instantiated again?

Comment: @FrankModica you're right I'm not sure...in fact that might be the case

Comment: @FrankModica but actually it doesn't really make sense : the controller would be destroyed and instantiated only if I didn't preventDefault(). Here the event is fired twice even if I preventDefault()

Comment: So if you restart your site, and navigate to this controller once, then navigate away and confirm you want to stay, the next time you navigate you get the message twice?

Comment: @FrankModica go to site -> navigate to controller -> before navigating away (to a url managed by same controller) i get prompted twice

Comment: Is more than one instance of this controller in play when you first navigate?

Comment: @FrankModica no only one

Comment: You should put a breakpoint before this.`$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart'` to see if it's being registered twice

Comment: ok good suggestion

Comment: Where is this being registered? In the constructor() or an $onInit()?

Comment: In the constructot

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but it's a pattern we use. Register your $stateChangeStart as you have (I'm shortening it for simplicity's sake) but with a minor modification:

```
const deregisterStateChangeStart =
  this.$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', this.foo.bind(this));
```

I'm assuming you do this in the $onInit() of the controller. Then add this:

```
this.$scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
  deregisterStateChangeStart();
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `this.foo.bind(this)` ?

Comment: I was going to post this but was waiting to see if this is the full problem, since the OP says they get the message twice even during the first navigation.

Comment: It was just to shorten his code, so I didn't have to write it all out again. The only change is the const addition.

Comment: Yep @FrankModica he definitely needs the $destroy or it's going to be a memory problem.

Comment: @rrd ok let me try this

Comment: @rrd nope it's still firing twice

Comment: @rrd all of the code is written in the constructor, not in the onInit

Comment: I'd suggest moving it into the $onInit() as it's a good practice anyway, see if you still get the same issue.